# Dropbox plug-in dont work. 5.1.5 Hera

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-files, dropbox

What did i wrong?

```
mohn@brake-old:~/Dropbox$ io.elementary.files
** Message: 09:11:14.490: Application.vala:50: Report any issues/bugs you might find to https://github.com/elementary/files/issues

** (io.elementary.files:3739): WARNING **: 09:11:14.528: PluginManager.vala:134: Failed to load module from path '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/io.elementary.files/plugins/libpantheon-files-dropbox.so': libpantheon-files-core.so.0: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

File not found? Realy?
How fix it?

Comment: Please open an issue here: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues

Comment: Note that little or no work is being done to maintain this plugin, in the absence of specific issues raised about it. It is hoped to replace it in the future with a general "cloudproviders.plugin".  I just installed it, and the DropBox client from the website and I get the same error. I'll look into it further.

Comment: I have pushed a pull request that fixes this for me here: https://github.com/elementary/files/pull/1380

Comment: The fix has now been merged into master but, unless you can compile and install the master source you will not experience it until the next Files stable release.

Comment: https://github.com/elementary/files/tree/dropbox-plugin worked fine for me as well! Thanks! (I cannot upvote, since I still haven't got enough reputation). An important detail is that you have to checkout the "dropbox-plugin" branch and follow the instructions from README.md from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Jeremy Wootten](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/3911/jeremy-wootten) .
I downloaded and installed the souce of dropbox-plugin from https://github.com/elementary/files/tree/dropbox-plugin
It's working.